# Column available in data frame but not getting while slicing the data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sparse-matrix, keyerror

While slicing the pivotted data frame unable to get the column names and throwing error below.Unable to find out what is happening as though columns available it is not extracted during slicing the dataframe.
Data set is 'MovieLens 100K Dataset'

Data set is

```
movieRatings=ratings.pivot_table(index=['user_id'],columns=['title'],values=['rating'])
```

Out of 'movieRatings.head()' as below

```
    rating
title   'Til There Was You (1997)   1-900 (1994)    101 Dalmatians (1996)   12 Angry Men (1957) 187 (1997)  2 Days in the Valley (1996) 20,000 Leagues Under the Sea (1954) 2001: A Space Odyssey (1968)    3 Ninjas: High Noon At Mega Mountain (1998) 39 Steps, The (1935)    ... Yankee Zulu (1994)  Year of the Horse (1997)    You So Crazy (1994) Young Frankenstein (1974)   Young Guns (1988)   Young Guns II (1990)    Young Poisoner's Handbook, The (1995)   Zeus and Roxanne (1997) unknown Á köldum klaka (Cold Fever) (1994)
user_id                                                                                 
1   NaN NaN 2.0 5.0 NaN NaN 3.0 4.0 NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN 5.0 3.0 NaN NaN NaN 4.0 NaN
2   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.0 NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
3   NaN NaN NaN NaN 2.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
4   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
5   NaN NaN 2.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN 4.0 NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN 4.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN 4.0 NaN
```

Next statement

```
starWarsRatings = movieRatings["12 Angry Men (1957)"]
starWarsRatings.head()
```

Error message

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2645             try:
-> 2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: '12 Angry Men (1957)'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-134-9c0f30e1dc98> in <module>
----> 1 starWarsRatings = movieRatings["12 Angry Men (1957)"]
      2 starWarsRatings.head()

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2797         if is_single_key:
   2798             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
-> 2799                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
   2800             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2801             if is_integer(indexer):

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _getitem_multilevel(self, key)
   2847     def _getitem_multilevel(self, key):
   2848         # self.columns is a MultiIndex
-> 2849         loc = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2850         if isinstance(loc, (slice, Series, np.ndarray, Index)):
   2851             new_columns = self.columns[loc]

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\multi.py in get_loc(self, key, method)
   2660         if not isinstance(key, (tuple, list)):
   2661             # not including list here breaks some indexing, xref #30892
-> 2662             loc = self._get_level_indexer(key, level=0)
   2663             return _maybe_to_slice(loc)
   2664 

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\multi.py in _get_level_indexer(self, key, level, indexer)
   2927         else:
   2928 
-> 2929             code = self._get_loc_single_level_index(level_index, key)
   2930 
   2931             if level > 0 or self.lexsort_depth == 0:

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\multi.py in _get_loc_single_level_index(self, level_index, key)
   2596             return -1
   2597         else:
-> 2598             return level_index.get_loc(key)
   2599 
   2600     def get_loc(self, key, method=None):

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:
-> 2648                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2649         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2650         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: '12 Angry Men (1957)'
```

Comment: Try print(movieRatings.columns) see the list of column names - perhaps there is some extra white space you're missing?

Comment: Thanks. I tried to copy the same even directly from the data file. Space is not the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited - Original answer wasn't what the OP wanted.

The problem is with the way you created it. An array/list `values` argument is interpreted differently than a simple string. In this case, you need to just use the string one. If you use the array, you'll need to index with [`ratings`, ...].

So just change the declaration of the table and it should work.

```py
table = df.pivot_table(index=[..], values='JUST A STRING', columns=[..])
```

Comment: @nikochiko Thanks and tried the same with code as below. But getting the same key error.The pivotted data frame is not recognising the columns while slicing the data frame ```starWarsRatings = movieRatings[movieRatings['title']=="101 Dalmatians (1996)"]
starWarsRatings.head()```

Comment: @nikochiko    Tried the same with the dataframe prior to pivoting operation.It is giving the result. Post pivoting is not working.     ```ratings[ratings['title']=="101 Dalmatians (1996)"]```

Comment: Oops, I misunderstood the question. Okay the flaw is in the syntax.
See the result of: `moveRatings.index, movieRatings.values, movieRatings.columns` and then you'll see what went wrong. Instead of doing `values=['rating']`, you must do `values='rating'`.

Comment: @nikochiko Getting the same as below extract of the codes ```movieRatings.columns     MultiIndex([('rating',                   ''Til There Was You (1997)'),
            ('rating',                                '1-900 (1994)'),
            ('rating',                       '101 Dalmatians (1996)'),
             
            ...```next statement    ```movieRatings.index    array([[nan, nan,  2., ..., nan,  4., nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],```

Comment: Yeah, so you see that the index is not what you want. You'll be able to access the elements if you do `movieRatings['rating', '101 Dalmatians (1996)']`. So in the pivot_table step, you need to change the list `['ratings']` to simply the string `'ratings'`.

Comment: @nikochiko Hi. Changed the same and executed    .But getting the same key error                                                                                    ```movieRatings=ratings.pivot_table(index=['user_id'],columns=['title'],values='rating')                     movieRatings.index                                     
 Int64Index([  1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,  10, 943],
           dtype='int64', name='user_id', length=943)                              
          starWarsRatings = movieRatings[movieRatings['title']=="101 Dalmatians (1996)"]
starWarsRatings.head()```

Comment: No no. I mean use your original syntax. That should work. Like `movieRatings['101 Dalmatians (1996)']` will work

Comment: @nikochiko Thank you very much. It worked with out error and child data frame created.